# Qual loop é mais rápido em C: while ou for?

Tags: c, desempenho, loop, while, for

Sendo um laço `while` e um `for` que rodem o mesmo número de vezes, qual é mais rápido? Exemplo:

`while`:

```
int i = 0;
int max = 10;
while(i<max){
    funcao();
    i++;
}
```

`for`:

```
int i;
int max = 10;
for(i=0; i<max; i++){
    funcao();
}
```

Comment: o `for` permite, desde C99, compartimentalizar mais a variavel de controle: `for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) { /* whatever */ }`

Comment: E vale lembrar que C11 já é o padrão no GCC.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A maioria dos compiladores produzirão códigos idênticos e não haverá diferença, mas só testando na versão específica de um compilador para saber. Fica a sugestão para fazer e descobrir por conta própria.

Exemplo de código gerado para `for`:

```
40047f:   c7 45 f4 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0xc(%rbp)
400486:   eb 0a                   jmp    400492 <main+0x1e>
400488:   8b 45 f4                mov    -0xc(%rbp),%eax
40048b:   01 45 fc                add    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
40048e:   83 45 f4 01             addl   $0x1,-0xc(%rbp)
400492:   83 7d f4 09             cmpl   $0x9,-0xc(%rbp)
400496:   7e f0                   jle    400488 <main+0x14>
```

Exemplo de código gerado para `while`:

```
400498:   c7 45 f8 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x8(%rbp)
40049f:   eb 0a                   jmp    4004ab <main+0x37>
4004a1:   8b 45 f8                mov    -0x8(%rbp),%eax
4004a4:   01 45 fc                add    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
4004a7:   83 45 f8 01             addl   $0x1,-0x8(%rbp)
4004ab:   83 7d f8 09             cmpl   $0x9,-0x8(%rbp)
4004af:   7e f0                   jle    4004a1 <main+0x2d>
```

[Fonte](https://www.quora.com/Which-is-faster-while-or-for-loops).

Ou seja, o resultado é o mesmo neste caso apresentado usando o mesmo compilador.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

As diferenças - a haver - não são significativas, mesmo para um elevado número de dados. A escolha entre uma e outra estrutura prendem-se mais com uma questão de estilo do programador e/ou legibilidade do código do que com questões de desempenho. A forma mais prática de aferir a diferença de desempenho acaba sempre por temporizar a execução e fazer uma simples análise estatística. Se alguém considerar importante, poderei fazer isso e acrescentar a esta resposta.

Comment: Qual é a razão do voto contra?

Answer (score -3):

O próprio enunciado já diz que ambos rodam o mesmo número de vezes... Ou seja, a complexidade desses algoritmos serão iguais. O(n^2).

Comment: A pergunta é qual é o mais rápido, e não qual é o mais complexo.Velocidade e complexidade podem se complementar numa análise, mas são coisas completamente distintas

Comment: E a complexidade de ambos é O(N) e não O(N^2).