# Função imprime lista while

Tags: c, while

Como faço essa função com o *loop* `while`?

```
void imprime(lista* recebida){
 lista* aux;
  for(aux=recebida; aux!=NULL; aux=aux->prox){
   printf("Informacao %d\n",aux->info);
  }
}
```

Comment: Algum motivo para isto? Não está bom assim?

Comment: Pretendo fazer com while pra entender bem.

Comment: Nossa o que aconteceu? sumiu @bigown

Comment: ?!?!?! Sumiu o que?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deve usar o que é mais adequado para cada situação. O `for` pode parecer a mesma coisa que um `while`, e até é até que você começa usar `continue`, aí há diferença porque no `for` o *statement* que deve ser executado em cada repetição sempre será executado não importa o que aconteça, enquanto que no `while` um `continue` fará com que ele não seja executado, e provavelmente não é o que deseja. Neste caso não tem `continue` então vai funcionar.

O `for` é composto por três partes, a primeira é uma inicialização, então basta colocá-la ante de tudo, a segunda é a condição e é ela que deve ser colocada no `while`, e finalmente a última é o "passo", o que deve ser repetido todas as vezes e você deve colocar dentro do `while` na última linha do bloco de execução.

```
void imprime(lista* recebida) {
    lista* aux = recebida;
    while (aux!=NULL) {
        printf("Informacao %d\n",aux->info);
        aux=aux->prox;
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Loop/WhileUnneeded.c).

Tem outras perguntas sobre o assunto:

- [Diferença entre while e for](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/61491/101)
- [Qual loop é mais rápido em C: while ou for?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/103194/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre o while, for, do while e foreach?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157512/101)
- [O que seria Iteração?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/185497/101)
- [Qual a finalidade do "continue" em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80589/101)
- [Deve-se usar break em for?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88747/101)

Answer (score 1):

O `for` é um tipo de laço que é mais conveniente que o `while`, mas este e o `do while` são mais primitivos que o primeiro.

Como você pode ver, o `for` é composto de quatro "partes":

```
for («inicialização»; «teste»; «pós-passo») { «corpo do laço» }
```

O `for` então executa *«inicialização»* uma vez, e depois confere o resultado de *«teste»*: se for não-zero, executa *«corpo do laço»* e *«pós-passo»* uma vez cada, nesta ordem, e vai verificar novamente o resultado de *«teste»*, executando *«corpo do laço»* e *«pós-passo»* até que *«teste»* dê zero. Aí ele continua com a execução depois do final do `for`.

Usando `while`, portanto, teríamos a seguinte estrutura equivalente:

```
«inicialização»; while («teste») { «corpo do laço»; «pós-passo» }
```

Usando `goto`:

```
«inicialização»;
label1:
if (!«teste») goto label2;
«corpo do laço»;
«pós-passo»;
goto label1;
label2:
```

Por que usar `for`, então, se `while` serve? Porque o programador, ao usar `while`, tem que ter cuidado para garantir que vai escrever o *«pós-passo»*, ou corre o risco de causar um laço infinito, visto que o pós-passo é que geralmente modifica o estado do programa de modo a garantir que o laço geralmente termine. No `for` você escreve assim que começa a escrever a estrutura e, portanto, tende a não esquecer este detalhe.  Mas às vezes o próprio corpo do laço já se encarrega de garantir que não ficaremos inspecionando o mesmo item para sempre.

Answer (score 1):

**Sintaxe:**

```
while (condição)
{
Instrução ou bloco de instruções;
}
```

Executa a repetição de um bloco de instruções enquanto uma condição é verdadeira.

**Fonte:** http://linguagemc.com.br/o-comando-while-em-c/

No seu caso você poderia fazer algo assim:

```
void imprime(lista* recebida){
     lista* aux;
     aux=aux->prox;

     while(aux!=NULL){
       printf("Informacao %d\n",aux->info);
       aux=aux->prox;
     }

 }
```